# Adding Annotations for coordinates MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am parsing this JSON file (correctly, it works with the UITextFields):

```
{"longitude":["37.786793","39.388528"],"latitude":["-122.395416","-78.887734"]}
```

ind creating MapViews, with the respective annotations in this way:

```
NSArray *allKeys2 = [DictionaryMap allKeys];

for (int h = 0; h < [allKeys2 count]; h++) {


CGRect mapFrame = CGRectMake( 400, e, 200, 110);

MKMapView *mapView2 = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:mapFrame];
[image1 addSubview:mapView2]; 







    NSString *key2 = [allKeys2 objectAtIndex:i];
    NSObject *obj2 = [DictionaryMap objectForKey:key2];




    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj2];
    float stringFloat = [address floatValue];
    float stringFloat2 = [key2 floatValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D anyLocation;

    anyLocation.longitude = stringFloat;

    anyLocation.latitude  = stringFloat2;







    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; annotationPoint2.coordinate = anyLocation;

    annotationPoint2.title = @"Event";
    annotationPoint2.subtitle = @"Microsoft's headquarters2";
    [mapView2 addAnnotation:annotationPoint2];  


    [mapView2.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];

    [mapView2.userLocation addObserver:self  
                                 forKeyPath:@"location"  
                                    options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)

                                    context:NULL];

    [mapView2 setShowsUserLocation:NO];

    [MapViewArray addObject:mapView2];

    if (MapViewArray == nil)MapViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [MapViewArray addObject: mapView2];


     }}

}while(g < f);
```

...I want the first map view to show the first coordinate pin, and the second to show the second pair of coordinates. But now, it is plotting on all the map views the same pin, corresponding to the last coordinates, and not to the first and second... respectively. This method works for the UITextField text, so I can't find the problem.

Please help!!

EDIT:

```
NSString *filenameMap = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@Map", destDir, NavBar.topItem.title];

NSString *MapPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Map", NavBar.topItem.title]];

[self.restClient loadFile:filenameMap intoPath:MapPath];


NSString *fileContentMap = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:MapPath];  

SBJsonParser *parserMap = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *dataMap = (NSDictionary *) [parserMap objectWithString:fileContentMap error:nil];  


NSArray *MaparrayLongitude = [dataMap objectForKey:@"longitude"];
NSArray *MaparrayLatitude = [dataMap objectForKey:@"latitude"];


NSDictionary* DictionaryMap = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:MaparrayLatitude forKeys:MaparrayLongitude];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another take:

You probably don't want to map your latitudes to longitudes in DictionaryMap. How about making an NSArray of NSDictionaries, where each dictionary has a "latitude" key and a "longitude" key?

Also, you have "[MapViewArray addObject: mapView2]" twice in your code.

And what is "g"? Maybe add some logging to your loop so you can see what's being created?

Comment: No, I actually want to create many map views, each with one annotation. The first map view has the first pin coordinates, the second map view has the second pin coordinates...

Comment: Look at my edit, I added the code I use to parse the file, maybe it helps, because the code you provide gives my errors (incompatible id)